# How to do .htaccess URL rewriting to include index.php in the URL?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a php-based system (called OJS) installed on my host. It uses SMARTY to create pages. I have pages with URLs such as:
http://example.com/ojs/index.php/foo

I want to be able to type http://example.com/ojs/foo in the address bar, and .htaccess would add the index.php into the url, and execute the new full URL so that the index.php can generate the required page.

Now I use the following in the .htaccess file in ojs folder.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
  </IfModule>
```

I have also tried so many other syntax and directives in the .htaccess. but non of them works. 
When I enter http://example.com/ojs/index.php/foo in address bar I get the page I want.
When I enter http://example.com/ojs/foo (or any page not defined in ojs such as http://example.com/ojs/blahbla or http://example.com/ojs/index.php/blahblahbla) it shows the main page http://example.com/ojs/

I did a test and I guess Rewrite rule at least is doing something. I made a dummy php code in file index2.php (in ojs folder), which echos the superglobal values. For this test I modified the rewrite rule to include index2.php, and I get following results:

- for address: http://example.com/ojs/ (as desired) no URL rewriting is done, since I do not see the content of index2.php
- for address: http://example.com/ojs/anything I see the content of index2.php which echos the following values:

> ```
> $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']: example.com
> $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']: /ojs/anything
> $_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]: /ojs/index2.php
> $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']: /ojs/index2.php
> $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']: GET
> $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']:  
> $_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO']: /anything
> __FILE__: /home/user/public_html/ojs/index2.php
> ```

Can anyone think of why it works with index2.php and it does not work with index.php ?

My configuration if it helps:

> PHP version  5.3.29, 
>   Apache version    2.2.29, 
>   host: Cpanel, Shared Linux host,
>   I do not have access to the main error log or Apache config file.

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 1):

I Think this is similar to CodeIgniter where we remove index.php from url.
You can use below .htaccess code to remove index.php from url. You must have to put below code to your root folder of project.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried. but still it does not work.

Comment: Hey there, You need give the read & right permission to .htaccess file.

Comment: it has 644 permission.

Comment: Can you check by giving 777 once it will start working then you can downgrade the permission to 644

Answer (score 0):

Frankly I suspect the OJS system is reading `REQUEST_URI` and expecting it to be of the form `/ojs/index.php/foo`.  It instead gets `/ojs/foo`, and since it doesn't recognize that, shows the main page.

I guess you need to tell (or modify) OJS to expect the `/ojs/foo` form.

Just to double check that Apache is not messing up, add a `R=301` flag for testing.  If I'm right, you should get a redirect to `/ojs/index.php/foo` – and when the browser follows that redirect, it'll work.  Of course, that's suboptimal, so fixing OJS expectations should follow. :)

(`QSA` is unnecessary here, by the way.)

Comment: Thanks @The Sidhekin.  I will test it. Just a question: Is not it the whole point of URL Rewriting with .htaccess, that when address http://example.com/ojs/foo is requested from the server, the Apache server first converts it to http://example.com/ojs/index.php/foo and then processes it. If Apache does it correctly, then the OJS is not supposed to get /ojs/foo, but it should get /ojs/index.php/foo. Am I missing something?

Comment: @cybergeek654 `REQUEST_URI` contains the path component of the original (pre-rewrite) requested URI; the rewrite leaves that alone.  The rewrite primarily changes what actually winds up getting served; in this case index.php.  It also changes `PATH_INFO` in your case, and it may optionally change other things besides.  (I don't know OJS, but I suspect it uses `REQUEST_URI`, and I would not be surprised if it completely ignores `PATH_INFO`, in which case just redirecting to index.php (without the /$1 `PATH_INFO`) would work the same.)

Comment: I see now. Is there a way I can avoid modifying OJS code, and get this working?

Comment: @cybergeek654 To change `REQUEST_URI`? I think that would mean redirecting.  Or proxying, perhaps?  But I don't think I'd bother with either.  Instead, I'd look into OJS configuration, and see if it doesn't allow for this.

Comment: OJS has a configuration file in which I can set RESTful URL on, By doing so all the URLS created in the OJS pages will be in the form example.com/ojs/foo and index.php is eliminated from URLS. Also, FAQ of OJS says I should set the .htaccess in my server to do the URL rewriting to include index.php in URLs requested by user. The code they say I should put in .htaccess is exactly the one I pasted in my question. I dunno why it does not work!

Comment: I also inserted some lines in my index2.php test file, so when I access the url http://example.com/ojs/foo in my browser, I get the following php values echoed: (for formatted text see the main question. I updated it there).
$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']:   <br/> 
$_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO']: /foo  <br/> 
__FILE__: /home/user/public_html/ojs/index2.php  <br/> 
should the PATH_INFO be empty?×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes

Comment: by the way, when adding R=301 in the rewrite rule, it works. Exactly as desired behavior.

Comment: @cybergeek654 `ORIG_PATH_INFO` is something php does: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php – it contains the `PATH_INFO` as it was before php started messing with it. I don't know why php does this, and I still don't know what OJS is looking for, but apparently, yes, after php has "processed" `PATH_INFO`, it may well be empty.